# MS Access SetFocus not working on AfterUpdate event

Tags: ms-access, events, stored-procedures, setfocus

I have three related fields on a form: a textbox for a date to be entered [Qtr1Date1] and two comboboxes with reason choices [Qtr1Date1Reason] and initiator choices [Qtr1Date1Changer]. When the user changes the date textbox - I have the AfterUpdate event changing the color of the comboboxes and blanking them out. I would like the user to be directed to selecting a choice in each one (to update the audit trail) and not being able to proceed until doing so.  I have looked at several other posts about the SetFocus not working, and order of key choices, but I am not sure why mine is not working. I am able to click on other fields on the form.

I have tried:
-Entering blanking out in BeforeUpdate instead.
-Validation Rule for combobox of Not Null (does not recognize initial blanking out)
-Adding another control to setfocus to cancel order key events and then setting back to desired set focus control

```
Private Sub Qtr1Date1_AfterUpdate()
     Call LogChanges(StoreCode)
     Qtr1Date1Reason = ""
     Qtr1Date1Changer = ""
     Qtr1Date1Reason.BackColor = RGB(244, 66, 113)
     Qtr1Date1Changer.BackColor = RGB(244, 66, 113)
     Me.Qtr1Date1Reason.SetFocus
End Sub
```

[image]

Update: What I have done now to workaround not knowing how to make them enter a choice, is changed the reason and initiator to "Accounting Error" / "Accounting" and then entered a validation rule in those those fields that an entry must be made if there is a date, so they either choose themselves as the culprit or make another selection.

[image: Workaround]

```
Private Sub Qtr1Date1_AfterUpdate()
     Call LogChanges(StoreCode)
     Qtr1Date1Reason = "Accounting Error"
     Qtr1Date1Changer = "Accounting"
     Qtr1Date1Reason.BackColor = RGB(244, 66, 113)
     Qtr1Date1Changer.BackColor = RGB(244, 66, 113)
     Me.Qtr1Date1Reason.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: "Not working" means what - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? Does the combobox already get focus after the date is entered? Set TabOrder property and probably don't need SetFocus.

Comment: The cursor does indeed move to the Change Reason field whether I push Tab or Enter, but I'd like it to prevent them from navigating away from it without making a selection. Am I using the wrong function altogether?

Comment: Try using the `LostFocus` event to make the cursor move to another field when this one loses focus. Note that that also fires when not changing the field. The `BeforeUpdate` event is the right event to check if the entered value is valid, and should be accepted. You can use the `Cancel` parameter in the `BeforeUpdate` event to reject changes.

Comment: The BeforeUpdate event will not prevent user entering and then leaving control without inputting data - 'tabbing through'. So using the Validation Rule should keep them on the control until value is entered/selected. If user is restricted to the listed items then combobox BeforeUpdate should not be needed. Don't use empty string to 'blank' control. I don't allow empty strings in fields. Set to Null.

Comment: @Erika could you be a little more clear about what the exact issue is you want help with?

Comment: I don't want them to physically be able to click anywhere else on the form unless they select a Change Reason AND Change Initiator after they change the Date in the text box to a new date.

Comment: It kind of works now that I changed the AfterUpdate to automatic selection to "Accounting error" (instead of empty strings), but only because they are not going to want to keep that as the accounting user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original Validation Rule was testing for Null. Code was setting combobox to empty string and empty string is not same as Null. To resolve issue of "does not recognize initial blanking out" try setting comboboxes to Null instead of empty string.

I don't allow empty strings in fields.

Comment: I don't really see how that answers this question (in my setup, `Control = ""` blanks it out just fine). Could you elaborate on it a bit further? Now it looks more like a comment to me.

Comment: The empty string blanks the control but Validation Rule was testing for Null and since value was empty string of course the validation failed. Seemed that was main source of Erika's issue.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining. I'd personally solve that by adjusting the validation rules, but your approach should be valid too.